# Creating a matrix programmatically in (base) R with some calculations and column slicing

Tags: r

I want to be able to take any factor (I'll provide a 4 level but the solution should be extensible).  Do some scaling of the factor levels **one by one** (not the whole factor with all levels, and return a n by n (again the example will be 4 x 4) matrix of the data.

My factor (reproducible data)

```r
MyFactor <- structure(c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L,
            4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L,
            2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L,
            4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L,
            4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L,
            4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L,
            1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L,
            4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L,
            4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L,
            4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L,
            4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 3L,
            2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L,
            3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L),
            .Label = c("AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD"), class = "factor")
```

My desired results

```r
desired_results <-
   matrix(c(2.70123428577876, -0.368350129878921, -0.368350129878921, -0.368350129878921,
            -0.240645076637884, 4.13471995314182, -0.240645076637884, -0.240645076637884,
            -0.332499, -0.332499, 2.992491, -0.332499,
            0.61434012818914,   0.61434012818914, 0.61434012818914,   -1.61962397431682),
          nrow = 4,
          dimnames = list(c("AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD"),
                          c("AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD")))

desired_results
#>            AAA        BBB       CCC        DDD
#> AAA  2.7012343 -0.2406451 -0.332499  0.6143401
#> BBB -0.3683501  4.1347200 -0.332499  0.6143401
#> CCC -0.3683501 -0.2406451  2.992491  0.6143401
#> DDD -0.3683501 -0.2406451 -0.332499 -1.6196240
```

I know how to produce the "columns" of the matrix one by one.  I know that the *diagonal* will always be populated from for example  `firstcolumn[2,]` since [2,] contains `TRUE` and rest are false, AAA = AAA is TRUE.

So I can produce the columns but honestly I'm not very good with matrix math and I'm hoping someone can show me how to be efficient, I've been struggling with a for loop.

```r
firstcolumn <- unique(scale(MyFactor == levels(MyFactor)[[1]]))
secondcolumn <- unique(scale(MyFactor == levels(MyFactor)[[2]]))

# mapping the first column

desired_results[1,1] <- firstcolumn[2,]
desired_results[2,1] <- firstcolumn[1,]
desired_results[3,1] <- firstcolumn[1,]
desired_results[4,1] <- firstcolumn[1,]
```

Base preferred but beggars can't be choosers I guess.

Thank you.

Comment: Are those numbers in the desired_results correct e.g. CCC - AAA value is -0.3683 and with `AAA - CCC` is 0.332499

Comment: Yes they are @Akrun, I know how to do it manually just not efficiently and across cases.

Comment: Literally did it by hand, for all four levels and then built the desired result by hand.  Cutting and pasting.Yes I can confirm your sapply only generates two rows.

Comment: For me, the  `sapply(levels(MyFactor), function(lvl) unique(scale(MyFactor == lvl)))` gives the output of the four levels that you showed

Comment: I need the rest of the "off diagonals" populated with answers too.  It has to be a full 16 cell matrix.  `firstcolumn[2,]` is the diagonal value cell [1,1] but the other 3 have to be `firstcolumn[1,]` 3 times.

Comment: Yes cutting and pasting is not good!  I fixed the desired results properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option where we create a `matrix` of `NA` with predefined dimensions based on the number of levels (`nlevels`) of the 'MyFactor', loop over the `levels`, do the `scale`ing, and assign the values in the column based on the index

```
n <- nlevels(MyFactor)
lvls <- levels(MyFactor)
m1 <- matrix(ncol = n, nrow = n, dimnames = list(lvls, lvls))
for(i in seq_along(lvls)) {
       tmp <- unique(scale(MyFactor == lvls[i]))[,1]
       m1[i,i] <- tmp[2]
       m1[-i,i] <- tmp[1]
  }

m1
#           AAA        BBB       CCC        DDD
#AAA  2.7012343 -0.2406451 -0.332499  0.6143401
#BBB -0.3683501  4.1347200 -0.332499  0.6143401
#CCC -0.3683501 -0.2406451  2.992491  0.6143401
#DDD -0.3683501 -0.2406451 -0.332499 -1.6196240
```

Comment: Incredible thank you.  I know what I wanted to do just kept stumbling

Comment: Thanks again @akrun.  I paid it forward https://stackoverflow.com/a/62323901/9190034